# Accessing to enum values by '::' in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have class like following:

```
class Car  
{  
public:  
    Car();  
    // Some functions and members and <b>enums</b>  
    enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Black
    };  
    Color getColor();
    void setColor(Color);  
private:  
    Color myColor;
}
```

I want to:

1. access to `Color` values as `Color::Red`. It is really hardly to understand code when `Car::Red` is used, when class have a lot enums, subclasses etc.
2. use type `Color` as function argument or return value
3. use variable type `Color` in `switch`

I know 3 partial solutions:

1. Using embedded class `Color` and enum in it
2. Using embedded namespace `Color` and enum in it
3. Using `enum class`

1 and 2 solutions solves a `Color::Red` accession problem, but I can't use functions like `Color getColor()` and `void setColor(Color)`.

3 solution has a problem: VS2010 doen't support `enum class`. GCC v.4.1.2 doesn't support it too. I don't know about later versions of gcc.

Yes, I'm working on cross-platform project.
I have found [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/299161-c-using--to-get-enum-members/page__view__findpost__p__2898948) solution, but it seems ... heavy.
I hope somebody can help me here :)

Comment: GCC 4.6 (with `-std=c++0x`) supports `enum class`, and also allows `Color::Red` for regular enums.

Comment: side note, please indent code with 4 spaces instead of using pre/code tags

Comment: I found than VS2010 has **partially** support of [Strongly typed enums](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In current C++ (i.e. C++11 and beyond), you *can* already access enum values like that:

```
enum Color { Red };
Color c = Color::Red;
Color d = Red;
```

You can go further and enforce the use of this notation:

```
enum class Color { Red };
Color c = Color::Red;
// Color d = Red;   <--  error now
```

And on a sidenote, you now define the underlying type, which was previously only possible with hacky code (`FORCEDWORD` or so anyone?):

```
enum class Color : char { Red };
```

Comment: You are right, but there is no compilers with full support C++11 features. Yes, GCC 4.6 and 4.7 supports it, but my project must be compiled for Windows too. VS2010 doesn't supports it. May be you know the some patch for it?

Comment: You can try MinGW, which is the windows port of GCC. MSVC is closed source and there are no patches.

Comment: `// Color d = Red;   <--  error now` is not giving any error at the moment. Also I can acces the values from the enum declared as a global one by typing their names (e.g `cout << Red << endl;`)

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu: Did you declare it as `enum class` or just `enum`?

Comment: I declared them just `enum`

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu: That's the reason. With only `enum`, the `Color::Red` notation is just optional. Only if you declare it `enum class`, `Color::Red` is mandatory.

Answer (score 7):

Name the enum inside the nested class (as example one):

```
class Car
{
public:
    struct Color
    {
        enum Type
        {
            Red,
            Blue,
            Black
        };
    };

    Color::Type getColor();
    void setColor(Color::Type);
};
```

Comment: You can also mention about `C++11` feature `enum class`.

Comment: And use getter and setter of `Color` in getter and setter of `Car`?

Comment: The `Color::` part is not needed here?

Comment: @Konrad Woops, fixed my example so now it's needed (since `Color` is intended to be a nested class).

Comment: @iammilind The OP doesn't want to use `enum class` because it's not uniformly supported across all needed platforms.

Answer (score 5):

When I want to do something like this I tend to use a namespace and a typedef outside of th namespace (though usually I'm doing this globally rather than inside a class).  Something like this:

```
namespace colors 
{
    enum Color 
    {
        Red,
        Blue
        ...
    }
}
typedef colors::Color Color;
```

This way you use the namespace to get at the actual colors, but the `Color` type itself is still globally accessible:

```
Color myFav = colors::Red;
```

Comment: VS2010 : error C2059: syntax error : 'namespace' | GCC 4.1.2 :  error: expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'

Comment: @Jury Probably because you're not allowed to declare namespaces inside classes.  Like I said, I usually do this globally.  You can always use a nested class if you really want to keep it within a class - the principle's the same.

Comment: The typedef isn't really necessary, and I would just put Color as the namespace name and not give the enum a name. I use the namespace method all the time since it's so elegant. Here's some more information about using enums: http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/enumeration-and-arrays/

Comment: @alex The typedef isn't neccesary, but it's a lot nicer to have a typedef than it is to type `colors::Color` every time you want to store an enum value somewhere.  As for not giving the enum a name - what if you want to use the enum type later on?  I guess you're maybe implying you should just use an int, but why throw away type information (and therefore type-safety) like that?

Comment: @obmarg I figured the namespace would encapsulate the enum so it would be used within the namespace so i could just use Color::Red (if the namespace is Color and the enum doesn't have a name).

Comment: @alex Yes, but what if you wanted to pass a Color to a function?  Without an actual name for the enum that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @obmarg I would use an integer type.

Comment: @alex I'd consider that very bad practice.  Firstly, you're throwing type safety out the window: normally your compiler could warn you if you try to use a non-Color in place of a Color - but not if you just use an int.  Secondly, it just makes things harder to understand for anyone reading the code - how is anyone meant to know at a glance that the function actually accepts values of the Color enum, rather than just any integer from 0 - 65536?  Since there's no type safety, anyone could misunderstand the parameter, pass in a value that makes no sense and things would compile fine.